# How to find if elements of a column in a data frame are string-contained by the elements of a column of another data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame `tweets_df` that looks like this:

```
    sentiment                   id                       date                                               text
0           0  1502071360117424136  2022-03-10 23:58:14+00:00  AngelaRaeBoon1 Same Alabama Republicans charge...
1           0  1502070916318121994  2022-03-10 23:56:28+00:00  This ’ w/the sentencing JussieSmollett But mad...
2           0  1502057466267377665  2022-03-10 23:03:01+00:00  DannyClayton Not hard find takes smallest amou...
3           0  1502053718711316512  2022-03-10 22:48:08+00:00  I make fake scenarios getting fights protectin...
4           0  1502045714486022146  2022-03-10 22:16:19+00:00  WipeHomophobia Well people lands wildest thing...
..        ...                  ...                        ...                                                ...
94          0  1501702542899691525  2022-03-09 23:32:41+00:00  There 's reason deep look things kill bad peop...
95          0  1501700281729433606  2022-03-09 23:23:42+00:00  Shame UN United Dictators Shame NATO Repeat We...
96          0  1501699859803516934  2022-03-09 23:22:01+00:00  GayleKing The difference Ukrainian refugees IL...
97          0  1501697172441550848  2022-03-09 23:11:20+00:00  hrkbenowen And includes new United States I un...
98          0  1501696149853511687  2022-03-09 23:07:16+00:00  JLaw_OTD A world women minorities POC LGBTQ÷ d...
```

And the second dataFrame `globe_df` that looks like this:

```
                  Country               Region
0                 Andorra               Europe
1    United Arab Emirates          Middle east
2             Afghanistan       Asia & Pacific
3     Antigua and Barbuda  South/Latin America
4                Anguilla  South/Latin America
..                    ...                  ...
243              Guernsey               Europe
244           Isle of Man               Europe
245                Jersey               Europe
246      Saint Barthelemy  South/Latin America
247          Saint Martin  South/Latin America
```

I want to delete all rows of the dataframe `tweets_df` which have 'text' that does not contain a 'Country' or 'Region'.

This was my attempt:

```
globe_df = pd.read_csv('countriesAndRegions.csv')
tweets_df = pd.read_csv('tweetSheet.csv')


for entry in globe_df['Country']:
    tweet_index = tweets_df[entry in tweets_df['text']].index      # if tweets that *contain*, not equal...... entry in tweets_df['text] .... (in)or (not in)?
    tweets_df.drop(tweet_index , inplace=True)

print(tweets_df)
```

Edit: Also, fuzzy, case-insensitive matching with stemming would be preferred when searching the 'text' for countries and regions.

Ex) If the text contained 'Ukrainian', 'british', 'engliSH', etc... then it would not be deleted

Comment: Looks like you'll need fuzzy, case-insensitive match, with stemming? Otherwise row 96 won't match 'Ukrainian' to 'Ukraine'. Or 'UAE' to 'United Arab Emirates', 'S. Korea' to 'South Korea' ,etc.

Comment: Also it would be good if you add URLs to where we can download those datasets (`read_csv()` can directly read from an URL).

Comment: @smci do you have an idea of how I might do the fuzzy, case-insensitive match, with stemming ? That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Convert country and region values to a list and use str.contains to filter out rows that do not contain these values.

```
#with case insensitive
vals=globe_df.stack().to_list()

tweets_df = tweets_df[tweets_df ['text'].str.contains('|'.join(vals), regex=True, case=False)]
```

or (with case insensitive)

```
vals="({})".format('|'.join(globe_df.stack().str.lower().to_list())) #make all letters lowercase
tweets_df['matched'] = tweets_df.text.str.lower().str.extract(vals, expand=False)
tweets_df = tweets_df.dropna()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try using [pandas.Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains) to find the values.

```
tweets_df[tweets_df['text'].contains('{}|{}'.format(entry['Country'],entry['Region'])]
```

And after creating a new column with boolean values, you can remove rows with the value `True`.

Answer (score -1):

```
# Import data
globe_df = pd.read_csv('countriesAndRegions.csv')
tweets_df = pd.read_csv('tweetSheet.csv')
# Get country and region column as list
globe_df_country = globe_df['Country'].values.tolist()
globe_df_region = globe_df['Region'].values.tolist()
# merge_lists, cause you want to check with or operator
merged_list = globe_df_country + globe_df_region
# If you want to update df while iterating it, best way to do it with using copy df
df_tweets2 = tweets_df.copy()
for index,row in tweets_df.iterrows():
    # Check if splitted row's text values are intersecting with merged_list
    if [i for i in merged_list if i in row['text'].split()] == []:
        df_tweets2 = df_tweets2.drop[index]
tweets_df_new = df_tweets2.copy()
print(tweets_df_new)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).